# What is the source of patches in those photos?

Tags: equipment-damage, sony-alpha

[image: patchy sun]

[Some more patches](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bd2guUHjXMJ/)

I think I healed some of the sun sized spots in the photo, but I did not touch the second photo. Is this the defect of the lense? I think those started appearing after one time I used the camera in rain. The lense is the cheap one that comes with sony a-6000. Those spots appear only in certain light conditions, so hard to reproduce. Could it be due to unclean lense? Or maybe even matrix?

Comment: Seems like dust on the sensor.

Comment: And please mark the spots you're talking about so that everyone can easily find them.

Comment: The location is not always in the same places. And the size of the spots is the same. I think it is more likely to be issue with lense.

Comment: If your lens is a bit dirty you wouldn't even notice it on the shots. Read here - [Dirty lens](http://kurtmunger.com/dirty_lens_articleid35.html)

Comment: None of those tests tested adding elements inside the lense. Or adding some water to it.

Comment: Do you see any additional elements or water in your lens?

Comment: Checked some other articles about dust on the sensor and I am convinced. If you want to make an answer with some examples of sensor dust, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like sensor dust. It probably is. The reason that it appears only in certain conditions is that dust spots get larger with a smaller aperture. Since you were shooting into the sun, the camera had no choice but to set a very narrow aperture and it made your sensor dust more visible.

This is easy to test. You stop down the aperture yourself, increase EC to +1.5 and shoot a white wall. The dust will be there and always at the same place. Do the same shot at F/3.5 and it will either not be visible or will be much smaller. Have you sensor cleaned by a professional to avoid risk of damaging it but you can learn later how to do it yourself with the right products.

Sometimes a spot of water inside the lens will look like that but it will eventually move and dry, so you will not get as consistant an issue as with sensor dust.

Answer (score 0):

...or in the interim, you could add the dust information in camera so the camera remembers and handles the dust blemishes and compensate in your recorded photos.

Ref:
Canon function is "Dust Delete Data"
http://learn.usa.canon.com/resources/blogs/2013/20131105_stoner_dustdelete_blog.shtml

Comment: What does _...or in the interim_ refer to? A suggestion from another answer? If so, please make your answer self-contained, or at least explicitly refer the specific answer. Answers do not always show up in chronological order on Stack Exchange sites, so make sure to answer with that behavior in mind.

Comment: Also, while the link to Canon's dust delete data is interesting, how is it helpful to the OP, who is using a Sony a6000?

Comment: scottbb

1. appreciate pointing the 'self contained' answers tip.
2. 'How is it helpful to the OP' - actually this is pointing to the right direction about technologies, I would appreciate an answer like that for myself if I was the OP. In fact stack exchange sites participants learn from insights and glean from exchanges like these, so easy mate

Comment: The point of my comment, is that your answer, while genuine in offering help, doesn't appear to actually answer the OP's question. It appears to be more of a comment to Itai's answer (but I can't quite tell, which is why I asked about that). It's great to think of the larger SE audience when answering questions, but above all else _address the asked question_. I'm not sure yours does: does the Sony a6000 have the equivalent of Canon's "Dust Delete Data" that you mention? If so, your answer is germane. If not, then your answer doesn't address the OP's issue. That's my point.

Comment: you answered your own pointless point scoring exercise. "does the Sony a6000 have the equivalent of Canon's "Dust Delete Data" that you mention? If so, your answer is germane" which the OP will check in his sony camera which I don't have.
btw what you are doing here in this thread is just point scoring. So I'm done here.

Comment: Please keep it polite.